# Access resolve from another resolve in AngularJS 1.3.x

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to access resolve from within another resolve in AngularJS 1.3.x ? I know it is possible in ui-router, but unfortunately I'm not using it in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested resolves is one of the features that ui-router adds, it is not supported by the stock ngRoute resolve feature. So your options are:

- switch to using ui-router
- restructure your multiple resolves into one resolve and do the "waiting" using normal promise / then / $q.all and similar things. You might not get the same reusability though.
- move the dependent code into the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Resolves all run at the exact same time, so it's not possible to direct the output of one into another. You could combine both resolves into one resolve that handles the flow itself, though.